# Is that hadoop 2 is atomic in transcation

Tags: java, tomcat, hadoop, transactions, atomic

I read through many blogs saying that hadoop is atomic in nature in version 2 on-wards,

But when i experiment it, It clearly shows that it is not atomic in nature.

**Scenario 1:**

I used the tomcat to upload 1gb of data in hdfs, But when i stopped the hadoop in between forcefully, The data transcation is not proper, Becoz old data (half of the data) still remains there in it.

**Scenario 2:**

When uploading the same 1gb file to another location of hdfs, I stopped the tomcat forcefully but still the data transaction is not proper, Becoz old data (half of the data) still remains there in it.

Anyone pls say where am going wrong?? Is that I need to do different kind of test in it.

Please do tell me whether the hadoop supports atomic transcation only through map reduce?

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Please define "Hadoop". Hadoop is not a product, so it makes no sense to say that _"Hadoop is transactional"_. If you are speaking about HDFS then you will have to apply the same algorithm than with any other file systems. If you are speaking about another product, then check its specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop's HDFS is not transactional. You need to take care of ensuring data is complete by yourself

Comment: When we write the data through hbase, Its transcational right, It has transcational feature!! Which is the best way to read the data through hbase or hive...

Comment: Hbase is not transactional in the RDBMS sense. It does provide atomicity within a row. see the sepcifics here: http://hbase.apache.org/acid-semantics.html